# How can I read input from the hosts keyboard when connected via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, keyboard, raspberry-pi

I'm currently experimenting with an RFID card reader that emulates a keyboard. When you connect a card, it will read out data from it and then emulate keystrokes according to configuration.

I've connected this device to a Raspberry Pi and connected to the Raspberry Pi via SSH.

Obviously, when the reader now emulates keystrokes, they land on the local tty of the Pi (and not in my SSH session). So I'm having a hard time getting to that input right now.

Ultimately, I'll be writing a piece of software to handle the input, but for debugging and development purposes, it would be quite helpful to get the keyboard input in my SSH session.

I tried the following

```
sudo cat /dev/input/by-id/usb-HID_OMNIKEY_5127_CK_01010053423438303000835748112531-event-kbd
```

Which *does* give some output when I connect a card, but it's not what I would have expected. It seems like that would be raw input data. I would love to get the keys as readable values.

The data that is being read from the `/dev/input` device makes a bit more sense when piping it through `hexdump`:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo cat /dev/input/by-id/usb-HID_OMNIKEY_5127_CK_01010053423438303000835748112531-event-kbd | hexdump
0000000 eef8 5138 219a 0008 0004 0004 0024 0007
0000010 eef8 5138 21ad 0008 0001 0008 0001 0000
0000020 eef8 5138 21b3 0008 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000030 eef8 5138 6019 0008 0004 0004 0024 0007
0000040 eef8 5138 602a 0008 0001 0008 0000 0000
0000050 eef8 5138 602f 0008 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000060 eef8 5138 9e97 0008 0004 0004 0023 0007
0000070 eef8 5138 9eab 0008 0001 0007 0001 0000
0000080 eef8 5138 9eb1 0008 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000090 eef8 5138 dd18 0008 0004 0004 0023 0007
00000a0 eef8 5138 dd26 0008 0001 0007 0000 0000
00000b0 eef8 5138 dd2b 0008 0000 0000 0000 0000
00000c0 eef8 5138 1b9a 0009 0004 0004 0021 0007
00000d0 eef8 5138 1baf 0009 0001 0005 0001 0000
00000e0 eef8 5138 1bb4 0009 0000 0000 0000 0000
00000f0 eef8 5138 5a15 0009 0004 0004 0021 0007
0000100 eef8 5138 5a24 0009 0001 0005 0000 0000
0000110 eef8 5138 5a29 0009 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000120 eef8 5138 989e 0009 0004 0004 0020 0007
0000130 eef8 5138 98b3 0009 0001 0004 0001 0000
0000140 eef8 5138 98b9 0009 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000150 eef8 5138 d71d 0009 0004 0004 0020 0007
0000160 eef8 5138 d72b 0009 0001 0004 0000 0000
0000170 eef8 5138 d730 0009 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000180 eef8 5138 15a1 000a 0004 0004 0009 0007
0000190 eef8 5138 15b5 000a 0001 0021 0001 0000
00001a0 eef8 5138 15bb 000a 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001b0 eef8 5138 541e 000a 0004 0004 0009 0007
00001c0 eef8 5138 542d 000a 0001 0021 0000 0000
00001d0 eef8 5138 5432 000a 0000 0000 0000 0000
00001e0 eef8 5138 92a3 000a 0004 0004 0004 0007
00001f0 eef8 5138 92b8 000a 0001 001e 0001 0000
0000200 eef8 5138 92be 000a 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000210 eef8 5138 d123 000a 0004 0004 0004 0007
0000220 eef8 5138 d131 000a 0001 001e 0000 0000
0000230 eef8 5138 d136 000a 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000240 eef8 5138 0fab 000b 0004 0004 0021 0007
0000250 eef8 5138 0fbf 000b 0001 0005 0001 0000
0000260 eef8 5138 0fc5 000b 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000270 eef8 5138 4e22 000b 0004 0004 0021 0007
0000280 eef8 5138 4e31 000b 0001 0005 0000 0000
0000290 eef8 5138 4e36 000b 0000 0000 0000 0000
00002a0 eef8 5138 8ca5 000b 0004 0004 0023 0007
00002b0 eef8 5138 8cb9 000b 0001 0007 0001 0000
00002c0 eef8 5138 8cbe 000b 0000 0000 0000 0000
00002d0 eef8 5138 cb2b 000b 0004 0004 0023 0007
00002e0 eef8 5138 cb3a 000b 0001 0007 0000 0000
00002f0 eef8 5138 cb40 000b 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

That *should* have been the input: `7643fa46`

Comment: if I understand your question, i'd guess that in the technical sense, it has very little to do with ssh, and you'd want some kind of keylogger perhaps written in C, running on the destination computer, and then you query it when you ssh to the destination computer.

Comment: @barlop: If I had to do *that* to achieve what I want, then it is not what I want to do. I will have to write "something" to actually grab the input in the end, I was just hoping for a quick approach that would allow me to test this setup in its current state.

Comment: it'd be an amazing security risk if ssh provided a feature to do it, and I doubt there's a native app bundled with the dest comp's distro by default.

Comment: @barlop: Well, I don't expect it to work without superuser privileges, that's for sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This hacked together script works for me for now:

```
import string

from evdev import InputDevice
from select import select

keys = "X^1234567890XXXXqwertzuiopXXXXasdfghjklXXXXXyxcvbnmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/by-id/usb-HID_OMNIKEY_5127_CK_01010053423438303000835748112531-event-kbd')

while True:
   r,w,x = select([dev], [], [])
   for event in dev.read():
        if event.type==1 and event.value==1:
                print( keys[ event.code ] )
```

It uses [python-evdev](http://gvalkov.github.com/python-evdev/) to read from `/dev/input/foo` and very dirtyly converts them to readable values.

This is what I get when I run the script and connect a card to the reader:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python test.py
7
6
4
3
f
a
4
6
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple hack to make it work easily until the next boot, assuming you have the required privileges.

Using the following command shows all processes running on the computer

```
ps -ef
```

To find the PID of the login/getty process from where the keyboard is currently read, we can pass the results of this function through grep.

```
ps -ef | grep tty
```

You could see something like

```
root     23698     1  0 18:17 ttyO0    00:00:00 /sbin/getty -L ttyO0 115200 vt102
```

Take note of the number in the second column - that is the PID. And the sixth column, which is where the keyboard is.

To halt that process, use the following command (substituting the number for whatever your PID is)

```
kill -stop 23698
```

Now, you can read the tty from where the keyboard keys are coming (tty is shown in the ps command)

```
cat /dev/ttyO0
```

The `cat` will read forever, outputting whatever is entered on the keyboard, until you kill it.

When you're done, and want to return to normal behaviour, you can resume the keyboard function with

```
kill -cont 23698
```

Of course that outlines the general idea. You could use your own program to read from the tty.

Comment: When I kill the /sbin/getty process, it auto restarts

Comment: That's `kill -s stop <pid>` and `kill -s cont <pid>` on busybox. And for me it was the `agetty` process that *didn't* have serial settings like `115200` but instead had the login options flag `-o`.

Answer (score 2):

Had to do this recently for a Hackathon, so I figured I would contribute what we ended up doing.

1. Set up autologin as root on tty1 (the main terminal where the keyboard device is dumping its input). The [Arch Linux wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/automatic_login_to_virtual_console) has good instructions. Reboot to get it to log in.
2. Copy the source of a small program known as 'ttyEcho'. One copy can be found [here](http://www.humbug.in/2010/utility-to-send-commands-or-data-to-other-terminals-ttypts/), but a Google search brings up many more. This program allows you to echo commands to another terminal. Compile on the target machine.
3. Now that we can run whatever on /dev/tty1, we just can just `./ttyEcho -n /dev/tty1 'cat > buffer'` to get everything input on tty1 to be added to a file. Instead of making an ever expanding file, use `mkfifo buffer` first to generate a special file which is just a named pipe - a FIFO queue which is backed by memory only.
4. From your SSH session you can now just `tail -f filename` to watch all keyboard input on tty1. From within python, `open('filename','r')` and keep calling `.read()` or `.readline()` on it to get the feed of keyboard data as it comes in.

This method was great for us since it avoids keyboard scancode parsing, and keeps a nice big buffer of the data without any code.