# How to make logkeys work over SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, logging

i'd like to use logkeys to log keystrokes on an SSH'able Linux box. Logkeys intercepts a Device, can this be used for SSH access? Does an SSH session use a Device? or does SSH bypass this level of input?

Comment: have you seen this? http://superuser.com/questions/562434/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-hosts-keyboard-when-connected-via-ssh

Comment: interesting, but isn't this just doing the same thing as logkeys (i.e. reading from a device)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`logkeys`](http://code.google.com/p/logkeys/) will log only keystrokes of keyboard(s) (USB or serial) connected to the machine `logkeys` is running on.

SSH daemon receives the input over a TCP connection not from a keyboard-like device. The devices `sshd` uses are [pseudo terminals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal). They work on a different level than a keyboard device and they are between `sshd` and the programs being run (not between `sshd` and the user).

`logkeys` does not work with terminal so you have to use a different solution. It would be rather a "session logger/recorder" as it does not log keystrokes directly from keyboard.

### Run a wrapper from `authorized_keys`

You can run a session recording wrapper instead of directly running a shell or a command. It could be specified in the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` by using the `commnad` directive. The users must use the [key authentication](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password) for this to work. It will not work with password authentication. A prepared script is available for example here: [Recording SSH sessions](https://www.jms1.net/ssh-record.shtml)

### Run a wrapper instead of a user's shell

Instead of a user's shell you can run a session recording wrapper. There is one: [rootsh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rootsh/) (basic functionality similar to the wrapper above). You can for example replace user's login shell.

Comment: thats great, as i'm planning on logging my own input for some quantified self malarky this works fine " ssh -p 12345 userid@server | tee -a logfile", obvious really :)

Comment: @user2846226: Thanks for showing your solution. Just a note: This will not work as a keylogger. `tee` will record only what is written to the terminal (including echoed keystrokes). As an alternative better could be `script -c "ssh -p 12345 userid@server"` because this tool has more options. See [`man script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script). --- Also when I see that you can capture on the client - `logkeys` on the client machine should work.

Comment: unfortunately i'm trapped in cygwin on the cleint but i have ssh and tee