# How to decode logged /dev/input data

Tags: linux

I needed to set up a quick keylog on my computer, and in my 30 seconds of brilliance the only thing i could think of was `cat /dev/input/event<keyboardID> > logfile`

Is there a way to decode that data easily? If not, where can i find documentation of the structure of this "file".

I Use 4.15.7-1-ARCH GNU/Linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read input from the hosts keyboard when connected via SSH?](https://superuser.com/questions/562434/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-hosts-keyboard-when-connected-via-ssh)

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly a duplicate but i managed to skimp it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to decode is not to cat it to a log file, but use `evtest` instead, which will decode it for you.

It's not difficult to decode, the layout is

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned short code;
    unsigned int value;
};
```

as described e.g. in `/usr/src/linux/Documentation/input/input.txt`, or the linux kernel header files. There you can also find the `#define`'s for the type there.

Comment: And i "now" know evtest is correct, however as i mentioned it was a mcgyver solution called log data now, parse it later